# Circuit question

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

I have a basic circuit question.In the circuit below I need to find Ix.However when I write the KCL equation what sign will I put with Ix because I don't know how it is flowing.Is it flowning down the 14Ω resistor?
Please clarify this ambiguity.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to worry about the sign initially. After you have performed the KCL and got an answer, if Ix is positive then your assumption about current flow direction is correct and, if the result shows a negative sign then the current is actually travelling in the opposite direction to your initial arrow.

Comment: But what if Ix and the current flowing down the resistors is the same and I accidentally write them twice?What then?
How will I know?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you write KCL equations the you start by arbitrarily assigning the current directions (arrows) at the node in question. Once this is done you write your equations following the convention that all current going in to the node (arrow head pointing to the node) as positive and all currents leaving the node (arrow head pointing away from the node) as negative. Finally as Andy had previously mentioned after solving the equations the sign of the response will verify your assumption regarding the direction of the current or show that it flowing in the opposite direction